# Scientific articles discovered false and useless several years after their publication

Tags: reference-request

I am looking for examples of important scientific articles that have been discovered to be false and useless several years after their publication. I mean:

1. they stated something interesting and important in a scientific field
2. they were accepted as correct at first, for years
3. many years later they have been found to be incorrect and not fixable or never fixed

Can you provide examples?

Comment: I'm reminded of the woman who published a paper in the 20th (or 21st?) century where she reinvented calculus, but that was merely not novel, so it doesn't meet the "false and useless" criteria.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/35468/widely-accepted-mathematical-results-that-were-later-shown-to-be-wrong

Comment: @shoover: The incident you bring up is discussed in the Academia Stack Exchange question/answers/comments [Rediscovery of calculus in 1994: what should have happened to that paper?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/9602/49593)

Comment: The entire corpus of work on eugenics and scientific racism qualify here. https://www.genome.gov/about-genomics/fact-sheets/Eugenics-and-Scientific-Racism

Comment: Would this include something like Lysenko in the Soviet Union?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lysenkoism

Comment: I removed my post on the [Mendelian paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregor_Mendel#Mendelian_paradox) but I think it is still highly debated and may not fit the bill properly.